# Amazon S3 Redirect rules for URL scheme

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jekyll

I'm running a Jekyll static site on S3, and all is going according to plan except for one small kink in the system:

Both sites' URL schemes go `/yyyy/mm/slug/`, but my old site would not prefix two-character months with zeroes (it would be `2015/1/` instead of `2015/01`, etc.) Therefore, old URLs will not redirect appropriately.

I've tried redirect rules such as:

```
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>5/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
 <Redirect>
   <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>05/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
 </Redirect>
```

to no avail. I can't imagine the only way to do this is to implement redirects for every date combination that is affected.

Is there any way to fix this with redirects and not having to change the structure of my new blog to match the old one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to micmic your old url scheme, you can set a `permalink` varaible in your `_config.yml` file.

```
permalink: /:year/:i_month/:title
```

This might do the trick.

See [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#template-variables)

Comment: Thanks, that will work for that purpose. However, I was enjoying the leading zeroes in the URL scheme, so I was hoping to solve it with a redirect instead.